# Extend model with linked table values. In cakephp3

Tags: php, mysql, orm, cakephp-3.0

Started to learn cakephp3. 
Having two tables

```
Task
-id
-task_type
```

and

```
Task_content
-id
-task_id
-some_key
-sove_val
```

In the result i'd like to get some object, which looks like:

```
{
id: Task.id,
type: Task.type,
title: Task_content.some_val (where some_key == 'title')
content: Task_content.some_val (where some_key == 'conent')
}
```

What is the best way to get this object, just by getting Task via "get"?

Comment: This object looks kinda JS-ish, if this is what you are looking for after all, then please mention that. Also in oder for people to recommend you a proper solution, it wouldn't hurt if you'd elaborate what for exactly you need such an object.

Comment: Yes, in result i want to get JSON object. But i want it to contain some business logic. All examples in Book are like direct get and set. As far as i understand pattern, i should't "compile" object in controllers action method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to crete a behavior to handle this. You can inspire from the TranslateBehavior, that does a very similar thing:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/ORM/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php